# running airflow job on specified dates

Tags: apache-spark, cron, airflow-scheduler, airflow

I need to schedule my spark v3.0.2 on job to run on specified dates (i.e. March31 and Dec31) of every year.
I am using airflow for scheduling.

how to handle this use-case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some options here:

## Option 1:

- Create a dag that has as the first step one PytonOperator that the date and fails if it not Dec31 or Mar31.
- Make this first step *required* to run the next step.

## Option 2:

- Create one dag that runs yearly for every date. This looks awful but it can be done easily with a single python file like this:

```py
# Create a dag for an exact date
def createYearlyDagForDate(startdate):

   with DAG(startdate=startdate,
            task_id=f"createdagdordate_{startdate.strftime(month_%m_day_%d)}"
             schedule_interval="@yearly") as dag:

      sparkjob = SparkSubmitOperator(...)

   return dag

for x in [datetime(2021,12,31), datetime(2021,03,31) ]:
   createYearlyDag(x)
```

The trick here is having a `task_id` for each dag. If you reuse task_id in the dags, you are overwriting the dag and will have just one declared.

Comment: I am submitting my spark job using spark-submit shell script. does the SparkSubmitOperator works for same too ?

Comment: I have created python function as told above but how to make it fail/pass to run second step

Comment: throwing AirFlowException to fail the job.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run your job only March, 31st and December, 31st, you can set a [cron expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression) in `schedule_interval` argument  in your DAG definition.

Cron expression will be `0 0 31 3,12 *` and can be translated to *run at midnight the 31st day of the month for month 3 (March) and month 12 (December)*. Thus your DAG definition should be:

```py
from airflow import DAG

your_dag = DAG(
    dag_id='your_dag_id',
    ...
    schedule_interval='0 0 31 3,12 *',
    ...
)
```

For more complicated cases such as *run April, 15th and August, 23rd* that cannot be defined with cron expression, I guess you should do as [Iñigo suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68771576/6807769)